# Replacing specific text within elements without having it affect elements with same class

Tags: javascript, jquery

The code below works for the first h3, but it also changes the second so I end up with both saying 'Country Filter', I need the first h3 to say 'Country Filter' and the second to say 'State Filter'. Any help, without altering the html, would be appreciated. thanks.

Here is the html:

```
<h3>  
    <span class="label">Browse by</span> 
    <span class="location">Country</span> 
</h3>
<h3>  
    <span class="label">Browse by</span> 
    <span class="location">City</span> 
</h3>
```

Here is the jquery:

```
if ($(".location:contains('Country')")) {
    $(".label").text(function () {
        return $(this).text().replace("Browse by", "Country");
    });
    $(".location").text(function () {
        return $(this).text().replace("Country", "Filter");
    });
}

if ($(".location:contains('City')")) {
    $(".label").text(function () {
        return $(this).text().replace("Browse by", "State");
    });
    $(".location").text(function () {
        return $(this).text().replace("City", "Filter");
    });
}
```

Comment: Why not simply `$('.label:eq(0)').text('Country')`, `$('.label:eq(1)').text('State')`? I'm also a little confused as to why you're using replace(). Does the possibility exist that those spans wouldn't contain that text?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Much simpler:

```
$(".location:contains('Country')").siblings().text("Country");
$(".location:contains('City')").siblings().text("State");
$(".location").text("Filter");
```

Why are you targeting the spans by the text they contain? Why would you ever need to change the contents like this? Just curious.

Comment: I only have access to django template includes and cannot manipulate the base html directly. Thanks for the help.

Comment: I dont know django but I am familiar with the difficulties of third party content.

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
//Find location that contains text
var countrylocation = $(".location:contains('Country')"); 
//As label is prev element, Here you can also use siblings
countrylocation.prev(".label").text(function () {
    return $(this).text().replace("Browse by", "Country");
});
countrylocation.text(function () {
    return $(this).text().replace("Country", "Filter");
});

var citylocation = $(".location:contains('City')");
citylocation.prev(".label").text(function () {
    return $(this).text().replace("Browse by", "State");
});
citylocation.text(function () {
    return $(this).text().replace("City", "Filter");
});
```

References:

1. [.siblings()](http://api.jquery.com/siblings/)
2. [.prev()](http://api.jquery.com/prev/)

Comment: You can also use `$(".location:contains('Country')").siblings(".label")` if there are more elements in each h3

Answer (score 0):

Identify the outer `h3` tag using an id

```
<h3 id="country">
    <span class="label">Browse by</span> 
    <span class="location">Country</span> 
</h3>
```

Then update your selector accordingly:

```
$("#country .label").text(function () {
    return $(this).text().replace("Browse by", "Country");
});
```

Comment: _"Any help, **without altering the html**, would be appreciated."_